# Add anchor to "Related" section, please

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-experience, related-questions

Sometimes a questioner is likely to benefit from looking at the Q&As in the "Related" section on the page with their question.

Unfortunately, that section is not usually visible as it is below The Overflow Blog, Featured on Meta, Hot Meta Posts, an advert, the jobs section, and the Linked section.

Directing the user to look on the right and way, way down could be easier if the Related section had an anchor that we could copy, which lead to the page scrolling the Related section into the viewport.

If you haven't got the aforementioned sections hidden, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69767473/shows-error-conversion-from-string-to-type-double-is-not-valid-input-string-is) of the Related section being a long way down the page where it has what could be the answers to the question.

Microsoft usefully add anchors to the sections of their documentation pages - [here is a sample](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#customize-the-formatting-operation).

Perhaps the "Linked" section could also have an anchor added to also make it easy to explicitly refer to.

Comment: The page showing all "linked" questions already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/69767473. It just isn't linked from the page itself when there are enough to fit directly in the sidebar with no overflow. However, I don't think a "related" aggregation page exists at all.

Comment: @CodyGray I was thinking more of scrolling the section into the viewport - I've added that to my request.

Comment: You can add `#h-related` to the url (it's the Related id), for example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412678/add-anchor-to-related-section-please#h-related . I know this doesn't solve the feature-request, but it's what you can use for now.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Thanks, it looks like it might be an easy feature request to fulfil to make it more convenient than remembering to add that to the end of the question's full URL.

Comment: Personally, I use a browser extension which shows all available link targets on the page when the extension icon is clicked (toggle on/off). This allows me to easily grab the URL for any such target (anchors and elements with an `id`). There are multiple browser extensions available which do this, which can be found with a search for something like "browser extension show anchors on page". The one I use, to which I've contributed code, is [Anchors reveal](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/anchors-reveal).

Comment: @Makyen Thanks, that's interesting. While I can see that such extensions have great utility, I have some expectation of Stack Exchange sites showing good usability without users needing to resort to browser extensions.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I agree with that. Unfortunately, SE's code isn't open source, so we can't just contribute content to implement things like this (even if they wouldn't accept all contributions, they'd certainly get a lot of people contributing code and fixing/implementing things). My comment wasn't meant to say that your request didn't have value or that it wouldn't be better for SE to implement something. It was intended to provide an alternative that allows you to more easily accomplish what you're looking for in the short term.